# Extracting an infinite subsequence

Tags: induction, foundations, big-picture

Suppose that $\{a_i\}_{i\in\Bbb N}$ is a sequence of real numbers such that for any $i\in\Bbb N$, there exists $j\in\Bbb N$ with $j>i$ and $a_j>a_i$. How to prove that $\{a_i\}$ contains an infinite monotonically increasing subsequence?

The "standard" argument goes as follows:

> Fix arbitrarily $i_1\in\Bbb N$, then find $i_2>i_1$ with $a_{i_2}>a_{i_1}$ etc; the resulting sequence $\{a_{i_1},a_{i_2},\dotsc\}$ is monotonically increasing.

While this sounds rather convincing, it does not seem rigorous to me. We actually have never constructed an *infinite* monotonic subsequence this way, the only thing achieved is constructing finite monotonic subsequences of arbitrary length. Is there a way to convert this argument to a rigorous proof?

I am not interested in alternative "topological" proofs (like using Bolzano-Weierstrass theorem) or deductions from known results (like the infinite Dilworth lemma). What I'd like to have is a direct proof, preferably a variation of that presented above.

Thanks!

Comment: Let $i_{k+1}$ be the least index $\gt i_k$ such that $\dots$.

Comment: @Andre Nicolas: please, see the comments to the answers below.

Comment: In formal set theory, say ZF, one can prove the existence without the use of AC.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Implicitly this seems to use a weak form of the Axiom of Choice, the (countable) [*Axiom of Dependent Choice*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_dependent_choice):

> (DC) For every set $X\ne\emptyset$ and every relation $R\subseteq X\times X$, if $(\forall x\in X)\,(\exists y)\, R(x,y)$ then there is a sequence $(x_n)_{n\in \Bbb N}$ of elements of $X$ such that $(\forall n\in \Bbb N)\,R(x_n, x_{n+1}).$

In the case of your proposition, $X=\Bbb N$, and $R(i,j) \iff a_i < a_j$. DC lets us conclude that there is a sequence $(n_k)_{k\in\Bbb N}$ in $\Bbb N$ such that for all $k$, $R(n_k, n_{k+1})$, which is to say, $a_{n_k}<a_{n_{k+1}}$.

However, DC isn't really needed in this case. Because $X=\Bbb N$, we can define the sequence $(n_k)$ by recursion, using the well-ordering property of $\Bbb N$ to define $n_{k+1}$:

- $n_0 = 0$;
- given $n_k$, let $n_{k+1} = $ least integer $j > n_k$ such that $a_j > a_{n_k}$.

Then once again, $(a_{n_k})_{k\in\Bbb N}$ is a monotone strictly increasing subsequence.

Comment: An exhaustive answer - thanks!

Comment: Now, with more exhaustion. (You don't really need DC.)

Comment: I am afraid I am confused now. Using induction, we can only prove that for every integer $k$, there is a *finite* sequence $n_1<\dotsb<n_k$ such that also $a_{n_1}<\dotsb<a_{n_k}$. However, the axiom of induction does not guarantee that there is an *infinite* sequence $n_1<n_2<\dotsb$ with $a_{n_1}<a_{n_2}<\dotsb$. Am I right?

Comment: Now with better terminology. This is "definition of a function on $\Bbb N$ by recursion".

Answer (score 1):

Note that an infinite sequence in some set $X$ is just a map $\mathbb{N} \to X$. Let $[1,n]$ denote the subset $\{1,2,\dots,n\}$ of $\mathbb{N}$. Now, you say that your proof gives you maps $f_n : [1,n] \to X$, that is, finite sequences, such that $f_n\!\mid_{[1,m]} = f_m$ for all $m \leq n$. But then the map $f: \mathbb{N} \to X$ with $f(n) = f_n(n)$ has the property $f\!\mid_{[1,n]} = f_n$. So in fact, your finite sequences patch together to form an infinite one.

Comment: I was thinking of such a "diagonal argument", but it is not clear to me (and I never said it) that the argument I sketched gives a system of maps $f_n$ with $f_n|_{[1,m]}=f_m$. Thanks for your input, anyway!

Comment: Let's say you have already constructed/chosen $x_{i_1},\dots, x_{i_m}$ with $x_{i_s} > x_{i_t}$ when $s > t$. In my notation this is $f_{m}$. Now your proof tells you to take $i_{m+1} > i_{m}$ with $x_{i_{m+1}} > x_{i_{m}}$. This gives you $f_{m+1}$. Recursively, you get all the $f_n$.

Comment: My point is that even if, for any integer $m$, we can construct $f_{m+1}$ given $f_1,\ldots f_m$, this by itself does not seem to mean that there is an *infinite* sequence $f_1,f_2,\ldots$. My question is whether one needs some version of the Choice Axiom or any other non-trivial fact to draw such a conclusion.

Comment: As BrianO already told you, this recursive definition works due to the properties of natural numbers, that is, given any map $F : M \to M$ and any element $m \in M$, there exists a unique map $f : \mathbb{N} \to M$ such that $f(1) = m$ and $f(n+1) = F(f(n))$. Note that for some recursive definitions the construction hidden in the map $F$ might require some Axiom of Choice, even though it does not in your case.

Comment: Can you elaborate? What are $F$ and $M$ in my case, and why the natural numbers have this property?

Comment: In BrianO's answer, you have $M = \mathbb{N}$ and $F$ mapping $i$ to the smallest $j$such that $a_j > a_i$. In general, given $M$ and $m \in M$ consider the map $S : \mathbb{N} \times M \to \mathbb{N} \times M$ given by $S(n,m) = (n+1,F(m))$. Then consider the intersection $G$ of all subsets $H$ of $\mathbb{N} \times M$ with $(0,m) \in H$ and $S(H) \subseteq H$. It can be proven (by induction) that $G$ is the graph of a map $f : \mathbb{N} \to M$ with the desired properties. Uniqueness also follows with induction. This is all done in 'Numbers' by Ebbinghaus et al.